# Validating integer field in DTO

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

My spring boot application has the following DTO for request:

```
public class MyAwesomeDTO {

    @NotNull
    private Integer itemCount;
}
```

I want `itemCount` to be either 0, or in range [3, 10]
. The latter can be validated with `@Min(3) @Max(10)`, but how can I validate the "OR" condition?

Answer (score 4):

There is a difference between `itemCount` being `0` or `null`. The `@NotNull` only guards against `null`, not `0`.

The easiest way to accomplish what you need is to write a custom validator.

Start by creating a custom annotation to trigger the validation:

```
@Target( { ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = ItemCountValidator.class)
public @interface ValidItemCount {
    String message() default "Invalid item count";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Next, create the custom validator:

```
public class ItemCountValidator implements 
  ConstraintValidator<ValidItemCount, Integer> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidItemCount validItemCount) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Integer itemCount,
      ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {
        return itemCount != null && (itemCount == 0 || itemCount > 3 && itemCount < 10);
    }

}
```

Finally, update your DTO:

```
public class MyAwesomeDTO {

    @ValidItemCount
    private Integer itemCount;
}
```